# Java LZW GIF Decompression

Tags: java, logic, gif, compression

I'm trying to decompress an LZW compressed GIF using [this](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.asp?#lzw_decompression) as reference.

While I think I understand the underlying logic, I'm having trouble reading in the "codeStream" correctly. As I understand it, the first `byte` of the "ImageData" block stores the number of `bits` used to "pack" the following codes, not including the two special ones **(clearCode & EOI)**. So the actual value I use is the **value of the first `byte` + 1**(lets call this value **bitsPerCode**).

I check after each code I read if Its value is equal to **(2^bitsPerCode-1)** and if it is it means we got to the max capacity of **bitsPerCode** `bits`, so I increment **bitsPerCode** by 1.

I'm also resetting **bitsPerCode** to its original value which is the **(value of the first `byte` + 1)** after each time I read the **clearCode**.

The "codeStream" is supposedly divided into sub-blocks where each sub-block's first `byte` indicates how much `bytes` of data will follow, and when a `byte` with a value of 0 is read we have reached the end of the "ImageData". I'm not to sure what should be done between each sub-block if the current code is not fully read. Should I use it as is? Should I discard it? Should I continue to read as if nothing has happen? Or maybe I should reset **bitsPerCode**? My code not doing what it supposed to is a good possibility as well.

The following code attempts to only read the codes and not decompress them as the method name suggests:

```
private List<Integer> decompressCodeStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // "is" assumed to be at the start of ImageData stream
    int lzwMinCodeSize = is.read(); // 8
    int bitsToRead = lzwMinCodeSize + 1; // 9 to account for the 2 extra codes
    int clearCode = (int) Math.pow(2, lzwMinCodeSize); // 256
    int eoi = clearCode + 1; // 257
    int bitsRead = 0;
    int currCode = 0;
    byte bitMask = 0b00000001;
    int blockSize;
    while ((blockSize = is.read()) != 0) { // ImageData stream is assumed to be in data blocks

        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            byte b = (byte) is.read();
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                currCode = currCode | (((b >> j) & bitMask) << bitsRead);
                bitsRead++;
                if (bitsRead == bitsToRead) {
                    result.add(currCode);
                    bitsRead = 0;
                    if (currCode == Math.pow(2, bitsToRead) - 1) {
                        bitsToRead++;
                    }
                    if (currCode == clearCode) {
                        bitsToRead = lzwMinCodeSize + 1;
                    }
                    currCode = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    assert result.get(0) == clearCode; // passes 
    assert result.get(result.size() - 1) == eoi; // fails 

    return result;
}
```

According to the [guide](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.asp?#lzw_decompression) the code must end with the **EOI(257 in this case)** code. But its not.

**Am I reading the codes correctly?**

**EDIT:**

I changed the method of reading in the codes to:

```
private List<Integer> readCodeStream(InputStream is, int minCodeSize, int clearCode) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // "is" assumed to be at the start of ImageData stream
    int bitsToRead = minCodeSize + 1; // 9 to account for the 2 extra codes
    int blockSize;
    while ((blockSize = is.read()) != 0) { // ImageData stream is assumed to be in data blocks
        BitStream bs = new BitStream(is, blockSize);

        while (bs.readLimit() > 0) {

            int currCode = bs.getBitsAsInt(bitsToRead);
            result.add(currCode);
            if (currCode == clearCode) {
                bitsToRead = minCodeSize + 1;
            } else if (currCode == Math.pow(2, bitsToRead) - 1) {
                bitsToRead++;
            }

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

the `BitStream` class:

```
public class BitStream {

    private static final byte BIT_MASK = 0x01;
    private static final int  MAX_BITS = 8;

    private InputStream       is;
    private int               readLimit;
    private int               leftOver;
    private byte              currByte;
    private int               bytesRead;

    public BitStream(InputStream is, int readLimitBytes) {
        this.is = is;
        this.readLimit = readLimitBytes;
        this.leftOver = 0;
        this.bytesRead = 0;
    }

    public int getBitsAsInt(int bitsToRead) throws IOException {
        int bitsRead = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for (; bitsToRead > 0; bitsToRead--) {
            if (leftOver == 0) {
                if (readLimit < 1)
                    return result;
                currByte = (byte) is.read();
                bytesRead++;
                readLimit--;
                leftOver = MAX_BITS;
            }
            result = result | (((currByte >> (MAX_BITS - leftOver)) & BIT_MASK) << (bitsRead));
            bitsRead++;
            leftOver--;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int readLimit() {
        return readLimit;
    }

    public int leftOver() {
        return leftOver;
    }

    public int bytesRead() {
        return bytesRead;
    }
}
```

Is seams the codeStream is now correct.

**Can some one confirm that this is correct?**

Comment: Codes can straddle sub-blocks. In my GIF reader, I repack the data by putting it all end-to-end and removing the whole notion of sub-blocks. Your implementation isn't correct because it doesn't properly handle the code size changes. There are plenty of reference implementations you can look at to fix your "inner loop".

Comment: @BitBank Tanks for the comment.  I actually already solved the issue of reading in the code stream. Unfortunately I face another problem, Decompressing them. Strangely enough I was sure that decompression would go smooth, but it's not. There are codes in the stream that I just can't find in the building up codeTable.

Comment: As I said, if you're using the code shown above, you're not handling the code size change correctly. The code size increases when your internal variable reaches the max code size (4095), not the code you find in the stream.

Comment: @BitBank 4095 is 16 bits, are you saying that I should start reading the codes 2 bytes ad a time? and then 17bits->18bits...N bits? I may have miss understood you.

Comment: @BitBank Edited the question. The codeStream seems correct(starts with clearCode and ends with EOI). Can you confirm this please?

Comment: The first problem to fix is this:  if (currCode == Math.pow(2, bitsToRead) - 1) {bitsToRead++;}. As I said above, this logic is not correct for handling the code size change. Next problem - picking up 1 bit at a time as you're doing is also quite inefficient. Finally, GIF codes can vary from codesize+1 to 12 bits per code (max value 4095).